# Interface binding

Tags: c, struct, shared-libraries

I am studying a shared library called "hmi-controller" in the Weston Project [1].
It has this following code snippet that is puzzling me at the moment:

```
/**
 * binding ivi-hmi-controller implementation
 */
static const struct ivi_hmi_controller_interface ivi_hmi_controller_implementation = {
        ivi_hmi_controller_UI_ready,
        ivi_hmi_controller_workspace_control,
        ivi_hmi_controller_switch_mode,
        ivi_hmi_controller_home
};
```

I don't understand what is going on here. Is this defining structure called "ivi_hmi_controller_interface"? What is up with these commas?

[1] https://github.com/wayland-project/weston/blob/2.0/ivi-shell/hmi-controller.c

Answer (score 2):

You can break it down to understand it:

```
static const struct ivi_hmi_controller_interface
```

This part declares a `static const` constant. According to where it is located in the source code, it is a global constant as well. In C, you need to prepend a `struct` for any structure identifier defined when you use it. So the identifier following it is of the type `struct ivi_hmi_controller_interface`

```
ivi_hmi_controller_implementation = { ....
```

You define an identifier here. Afterwards, you can refer to this global constant by this name.

```
... = {
    ivi_hmi_controller_UI_ready,
    ivi_hmi_controller_workspace_control,
    ivi_hmi_controller_switch_mode,
    ivi_hmi_controller_home
};
```

This is what your constant structure actually means.

Comment: Am I right to say "struct ivi_hmi_controller_interface" is the type of "ivi_hmi_controller_implementation"?

Comment: sort of. It is a bit ambiguous whether you should claim "const" to be part of the type.